# Matrices with llncs class

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, lncs

I have the following snippet to display a matrix equation using the regular `amsmath` packages:

```
\begin{equation}
S(x) =  
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_{15} \\
x_{14} \\
x_{13} \\
x_{12} \\
x_{11} \\
x_{10} \\
x_{9} \\
x_{8} \\
x_{7} \\
x_{6} \\
x_{5} \\
x_{4} \\
x_{3} \\
x_{2} \\
x_{1} \\
x_{0} \\
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}
+
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\ 
1 \\
0 \\
1 \\
1 \\
0 \\
1 \\
1 \\
0 \\ 
1 \\
1 \\
1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
```

However, when I try to compile this same code with the `llncs` class file (http://www.springer.com/computer/lncs/lncs+authors?SGWID=0-40209-0-0-0), which forces me to remove the `amsmath` package references, the following error is thrown:

> ! Misplaced alignment tab character &.
>   l.544 0 &
>   0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \
>   Clearly I'm making some simple error, but I'm not sure what it is. Does anyone see it?

Comment: Is the inverse misplaced? It should be on a square matrix.

Comment: Nope, but good eye!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath), you can set a `pmatrix` as an `array` with column specification `@{}*{<num>}{c}@{}`. This sets `<num>` columns with `c`entered content and not spacing `@{}` on either side of the matrix:

[image]

```
\documentclass{llncs}% http://www.springer.com/computer/lncs/lncs+authors?SGWID=0-40209-0-0-0
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  S(x) = 
  \left(\begin{array}{@{}*{16}{c}@{}}
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
    1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
    1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0
  \end{array}\right)
  \left(\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
    x_{15} \\ x_{14} \\ x_{13} \\ x_{12} \\ x_{11} \\ x_{10} \\ x_9 \\
    x_8 \\ x_7 \\ x_6 \\ x_5 \\ x_4 \\ x_3 \\ x_2 \\ x_1 \\ x_0
  \end{array}\right)^{-1}
  +
  \left(\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
    0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1
  \end{array}\right)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you wish to spread out the content a little more, add `\setlength{\arraycolsep}{5pt}` to your document preamble. [`llncs`](http://www.springer.com/computer/lncs/lncs+authors?SGWID=0-40209-0-0-0) sets this to `1.4\p@` (1.4pt) by default; much lower/smaller than the [`article`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls) default of `5\p@` (5pt).

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to prove to myself that it could be done without all those `&` characters and with many fewer `\\` macros.

```
\documentclass{article}%{llncs}%
\usepackage{stackengine}[2013-09-11]
\strutlongstacks{T}
\newsavebox{\matrixbox}
\newcommand\Matrixstack[1]{%
  \sbox{\matrixbox}{\Longstack{#1}}\left(%
    \abovebaseline[-.5\ht\matrixbox+.5\ht\strutbox-\dp\strutbox]
    {\usebox{\matrixbox}}\right)}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  S(x) = 
  \setstackEOL{\\}\Matrixstack{%
    0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  0 \\
    1  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  1  0  1  0 \\
    1  1  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  1  0  1  0  0  1  1 \\
    1  1  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0 \\
    1  1  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  1  1  0  1  1 \\
    0  1  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  1  0  1 \\
    0  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  0 \\
    1  0  1  1  1  0  1  1  0  0  0  1  0  1  1  1 \\
    0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  1  1  0  1 \\
    1  0  1  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0 \\
    1  0  1  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  1  0  0 \\
    1  0  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  0  1  1  0  0  1 \\
    1  0  1  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  1 \\
    0  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1 \\
    1  0  0  0  1  1  0  1  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  0 \\
    1  1  0  1  0  1  1  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  0}
  \stackMath\setstackEOL{ }\Matrixstack{%
    x_{15} x_{14} x_{13} x_{12} x_{11} x_{10} x_9 x_8
    x_7 x_6 x_5 x_4 x_3 x_2 x_1 x_0}^{-1}
  +
  \Matrixstack{0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]